# what happened to my DIV element?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have this simple piece of code:

HTML:

```
<body>  
    <div id="red">  ABC </div>
    <div id="blue"> ABC </div>  
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    width: 300px;
}
#red{   
    float:left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;  
    background-color: red;  
}

#blue{  
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

I see the red squara and the blue just next to it.

However, if I add the line "width: 100px;" in the #blue, everything is ruined:
The "ABC" jumps" one line down and there is no blue background.
WHY??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the other div is floated overtop of it. When you float something, any element that is NOT floated will have its outer bounds BEHIND the floated element. Therefor, the blue box is actually behind the red one.. but because the red is a block level element the text wont fit there, and so it sits underneath the red. float both and it will work

http://jsfiddle.net/AUZxY/

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure I understood this: "any element that is NOT floated will have its outer bounds BEHIND the floated element". Could you please explain it? :)

Comment: Removing the float from the #blue element and giving it a width wider than the #red element will show this, hopefull [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AUZxY/5/) helps you understand what Tallboy was talking about.

Answer (score 4):

Try floating both elements to the left, I believe [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sh8WB/) that I put together should be what you're looking for.

Comment: However, what is the problem with the original? ( I want to understant what is wrong to prevent it in the future :)  ) Thanks!

Comment: In that case look at Tallboy's answer. I responded the quickest, but you should vote him the answer since he also explains the issue.